# Adding Up and Down Arrows according to Order Type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting data from database through ajax & PHP, the returned data is shown as a table, i created a function to sort table column ascending or descending, i want to add arrows beside the column name to show up in case of `ascending order` & down in case of `descending order`, how can this be done?

**HTML Code**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d7a6f6be38.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="row">
   <div id="OrderTable"></div>
</div>
```

**Part of PHP page `searchorders.php`**

```
<?php
 $output.='<hr />
  <table id="SearchResults" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:auto;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Order No.</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Order Date</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Category Type</th>
        <th>Quantity in Kilos</th>
        <th>Delivery Date</th>
        <th>Order Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
 ';

 echo $output;
?>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
function SearchOrders()
{
    document.getElementById("OrderTable").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("NoData").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("Results").style.display = 'none';

    startDate=document.getElementById("Start_Date").value;
    endDate=document.getElementById("End_Date").value;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"searchorders.php",
        data:
            { 
               'StartDate': startDate, 
               'EndDate':endDate
            },
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data == "Failed")
            {
                $('#NoData').append("No data Found!");
            }
            else
            {
                $('#OrderTable').append(data);
                document.getElementById("Results").style.display = 'block';

                $('#SearchResults').DataTable({"columnDefs": [ {
                               "targets": [0,4,5,6],
                                "orderable": false
                              }]});
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Check out dataTables plug-in unless this is some academic excercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add up(for ascending) and down(for descending) arrows. I am using text inside `span` here which you can replace with icons or something but keep the `id` on them the same.

```
<th onclick="sortTable(1)">
  <span id="asc1">Up</span>
  <span id="desc1">Down</span>
  Customer Name
</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(2)">
  <span id="asc2">Up</span>
  <span id="desc2">Down</span>
  Order Date
</th>
<th onclick="sortTable(3)">
  <span id="asc3">Up</span>
  <span id="desc3">Down</span>
  Category Name
</th>
```

Then hide them in the css and style them more as you like

```
th>span{
  display:none;
}
```

Then write the jquery code since you are passing `n` to the function and you know the direction of sort too. so just reverse engineer the id and show that arrow.

```
$('th>span').hide();
var idChange = '#'+ dir + n;
$(idChange).show();
```